# SwiftUI - makes mac unuseable

Tags: xcode, swiftui

So not sure if this is just an issue I am having but, has anyone else noticed that the preview seems to slow down you mac? I am now wanting to turn that feature off because I feel its just useless. I have my device connected to the computer and personally I can run it on there.

I am wondering has anyone else had this issue.

Also preview seems to not show images that are using https://github.com/crelies/RemoteImage
So I am basically at a loss.

How do I disable the swiftUI preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Adjust Editor Option tabbar button and un-check Canvas

[image: demo]